# Design problem in wrapping Windows's Window API

Tags: winapi, wrapper

I'm writing an object-oriented window API wrapper for Windows in D, and I'm having a (non-language-specific) design problem.

Windows requires that all windows be previously registered with `RegisterClass`; extending an existing class requires replacing the window procedure. Furthermore, there seem to be two kinds of window handles: `HWND`s that need to be disposed (via `DestroyWindow`), and `HWND`s that don't (e.g. from other applications).

I have created a `Window` class, and so long as I'm just wrapping the `ShowWindow`, `UpdateWindow`, `FindWindow`, and other such methods, everything is fine and dandy. But as soon as I try to add a constructor with a `className` parameter to my class that calls `CreateWindow`, I run across a problem:

1. The given `className` must already have been registered by `RegisterClass`.
2. In order to register a new window class, I would need to make my subclasses of `Window` to somehow call `RegisterClass` before trying to create a new Window, either directly or indirectly.
3. In order for my design (and inheritance) to make sense, i would need to make sure that, for any given subclass of `Window`, all instances are actually instances of the same window class; namely, that all `className`s from a particular subclass are identical. (This is because the window procedures for all instances of a particular window class need to be the same.)

The problem is, there's no way to have an `abstract static` method (in order for Window to be able to ask the subclasses for their class info, and to register them once), and so I am forced to say something like `CreateWindow(this.className, ...)` in order to create a new window, which easily becomes problematic if my subclasses don't respect this rule, and give me a different class name per instance of the window.

Furthermore, I need a one-to-one mapping between the `WNDCLASS.lpfnWndProc` field and my Window subclass's (overridden) `WndProc` method. This doesn't exactly work, though, if I'm forced to get the method pointer on a per-instance basis, since it breaks the entire OOP design and messes everything up.

While it's possible for me to *enforce* this consistency at run-time, it's a bit ugly, and so it's not a great solution.

So, long story short, does anyone have any idea of an elegant solution to the problem of creating an `abstract static` method? I'm thinking of some design patterns like Factory and whatnot, but I'm not sure if they fit here... if someone thinks they might , I would really appreciate a little explanation on how it would fit into the design.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered reading the source of WFC?

Comment: Huh, I've never heard of WFC (related to MFC?)... I'll go look it up. However, I *have* tried to read the source of *System.Windows.Forms.dll* in the .NET framework, but the problem is that it's somewhat (read: extremely) hideous; I hope WFC follows a simpler design.

Comment: @bmargulies: Is [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/wfc.aspx) what you meant, or are you referring to a different library? Because this one doesn't even have much GUI-related API in it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I certainly didn't expect this...

I searched for the phrase `x86 thunks` on Google. And, as it turns out, I wasn't the first person to come across this problem (surprise!).

The first hit was the [*exact problem* and the solution](http://www.hackcraft.net/cpp/windowsThunk/) to this question about Window Procs, even though it had nothing to do with my query (or at least, very little to do directly)... hope someone else finds it useful too.

Comment: That's ... well, ingenious. I suppose. Not sure what's going to happen when that code encounters data execution prevention. Seems to me that the `SetWindowLong` technique would have been more reasonable. Somehow, I don't see that extra call to `GetWindowLong` as being a huge bottleneck, as the processing of messages is unlikely to be a time-critical part of the application.

Comment: Yeah, I thought DEP might do something bad, but for now I've been safe, so whatever. :D

Answer (score 2):

The standard solution for this is to give the base class two window procedures, [a static one and a virtual one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/04/22/410773.aspx).

The base class registers its class with the static window procedure. The static window procedure then invokes the virtual window procedure. Many people omit the `HWND` parameter from the virtual version since it can be obtained from the `this` pointer, but I'll leave it in just to simplify the story.

```
class Window
{
public:
    virtual LRESULT WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    { return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam); }
private:
    static LRESULT CALLBACK StaticWndProc(
        HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        if (uMsg == WM_NCCCREATE) {
            SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(
                 reinterpret_cast<LPCREATESTRUCT>(lParam)->lpCreateParams);
        }
        Window *pThis = reinterpret_cast<Window*>(
                                     GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA));
        LRESULT lres = pThis ? pThis->WndProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam)
                             : DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
};
```

Derived classes override `Window::WndProc`.

Comment: Do you know why ATL uses thunking instead -- is there a real performance decrease in using `GetWindowLongPtr` every time?

Comment: ATL doesn't use virtual methods so it can't use the virtual method technique.

Comment: It is unlikely that `GetWindowLongPtr()` will be a performance bottleneck for you... it's just doing a lookup on a field in the object associated with the window handle.

Answer (score 0):

The window proc doesn't have to be the same for all instances of a particular class name.

Typically, you'd use the `RegisterClass` function to set the *default* window proc for windows of that class.  When you create a new window that uses the class but you want it to override the default handling, you create the window and then call `SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, newWndProc)`, where `newWndProc` is a pointer to the new window's window proc.

The new window's window proc can then handle the messages that it wants to override, and call `DefWindowProc` for the rest.

To construct a window with a new class name, have the constructor copy the class info for the inherited class and create a new class that's identical to that one, except for the name.  Then expose a method that will allow the client to change class-specific things.  The API functions you're interested in would be `GetClassInfoEx` and `SetClassLong`, `SetClassWord` or `SetClassLongPtr`.

Inheritance still makes sense in this world because the *default* processing is the same for every window of a particular class, and inherited classes inherit the default processing from their parents.

You don't need anything like an `abstract static` method for this. All you need is the window handle.  You can get the class name by calling `GetClassName` with the window handle, and then call `GetClassInfoEx` with the returned class name.

Comment: Well, the issue is, once things become object-oriented, the user must no longer manually change the window proc -- he needs to actually subclass the class, and override the existing window proc polymorphically. So the user should never change the window proc, and so the same default window proc for each subclass should in fact be called for all instances of that class... and so I'm trying to find the best way to do that.